# DateBox with a format like MM,DD,yyyy

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I have a DateBox and I Want to show this format in my DateBox :  'MM,DD,yyyy' .

I saw this documentation ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-time-format) and I don't find my Format.

My code :

```
  var dateBox_delivered = app.createDateBox().setId('id_dateBox_delivered').setName('v_dateBox_delivered').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.??);
```

Comment: Try this http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Comment: I think it's not possible to integrate this on Google App Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get any other format than the ones available in the [ENUM list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-time-format) you referred to.

the syntax is as follows :

```
  var dBox = app.createDateBox().setId("FormDate").setValue(new Date()).setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT);
```

and the available modes appear in the autocomplete :

[image]

Switch to HTML Service and JQuery to get more possibilities.

or you could give a try to this *cumbersome workaround* that is approaching the functionality (although far from perfect... just a suggestion ;)

Test in a **new** spreadsheet :

```
function dateBoxFormatTest() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var textBox = app.createTextBox().setText(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MM,dd,yyyy')).setId('textBox').setName('textBox').setVisible(false);
  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox').setValue(new Date()).setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_NUM_DAY);
  var cHandlerDate = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(textBox).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  var cHandlerText = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dateBox).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('upDate').addCallbackElement(dateBox);
  dateBox.addValueChangeHandler(cHandlerDate).addValueChangeHandler(handler);
  textBox.addClickHandler(cHandlerText);
  app.add(dateBox).add(textBox);
  ui.showModalDialog(app,'DateBoxtest')
}

function upDate(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.dateBox, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MM,dd,yyyy');
  app.getElementById('textBox').setText(formatedDate);
  return app;
}
```